# iap v3 consumed items

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

Is there any way to get a list of all consumed items  in the app.

If I run:

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");
        if (result.isFailure()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "#### IAP Error: Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "#### IAP Query inventory was successful.");

        // Check for inApp-Items to consume (not subs)
        //getSkuDetails(): type: Value must be 'inapp' for an in-app product or 'subs' for subscriptions.
        if(!inventory.getAllPurchases().isEmpty()){
            Log.d(TAG, "#### IAP 1");
            int count = 0;
            for(Purchase p : inventory.getAllPurchases()){
                count += 1;
                Log.d(TAG, "#### IAP 2");
                Log.d(TAG, "#### IAP Inventory Item" + count + "=" + p.toString());
                if(inventory.getSkuDetails(p.getSku()).getType().equals(IabHelper.ITEM_TYPE_INAPP)){
                    mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(p.getSku()), mConsumeFinishedListener);
                }
            }
        }
        //          if (inventory.hasPurchase("android.test.purchased")) {
        //              Log.d(TAG, "**** IAP We have android.test.purchased. Consuming it.");
        //              mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase("android.test.purchased"), mConsumeFinishedListener);
        //              return;
        //          }

        //updateUi();
        //setWaitScreen(false);
        Log.d(TAG, "#### IAP Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
    }
};
```

I got an Inventory with all non consumed and not consumable items
but I look for a list which shows me all consumed items the user got from my app.

Can some one tell me if there is any way I can do this?